# Oracle 10g DB - How to give multiple users access to same db

Tags: oracle

My application has a db with many tables. Now there is a new application and i have to give them access to only one table. How can it be done...is it possible to create a new user which will point to the same db and have access to only particular table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE ROLE app_usr_role;

CREATE USER app_user IDENTIFIED BY password;

GRANT app_usr_role TO app_user;

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON table TO app_usr_role;
```

Comment: +1 Yep, this way the same set of permissions can be assigned to multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You need to use GRANT or REVOKE commands for this. First, you'd have to revoke unneeded privileges from your new user. See [here](http://psoug.org/reference/system_privs.html) scripts to list and revoke this privileges. Then grant access only to your table, like

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on YOUR_TABLE to NEW_USER
```

See more info here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php